# How can I create a query that show the result of combining two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have table A that shows vehicle activity by registration number by date. each rego can be active each day.

I have a second table, table B that shows a date, registration number and Status that I want to populate table 1 with.

The idea is to show every thing in table A that does not have an entry in table B and to keep a rolling record of this.

```
Table A
ABC 2019-05-17
XYZ 2019-05-17
DEF 2019-05-17
HIJ 2019-05-17
KLM 2019-05-17
NOP 2019-05-17
QRS 2019-05-17
TUV 2019-05-17
AAA 2019-05-17
DEF 2019-05-16
AAA 2019-05-16
DEF 2019-05-16
HIJ 2019-05-16
KLM 2019-05-16
NOP 2019-05-16
QRS 2019-05-16
TUV 2019-05-16
```

Table B

```
TUV 2019-05-17  PASS
AAA 2019-05-17  PASS
DEF 2019-05-17  FAIL
MOP 2019-05-17  PASS
AAA 2019-05-16  PASS
DEF 2019-05-16  FAIL
MOP 2019-05-16  PASS
```

I have searched a number of sites for help but I just can;t seem to track down what works

```
SELECT A.Date_, 
A.Rego, B.Rego, B.Status, B.Date_ 
FROM Daily_Activity A, Daily_Inspect B 
WHERE A.Date_=B.Date_ AND A.Rego=B.Rego
```

this works in part but I also want to show the data in table A that does not have a matching entry in table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN. This will return you all records from Table A and also matched results from Table B.

```
SELECT A.Date_, 
A.Rego, B.Rego, B.Status, B.Date_ 
FROM Daily_Activity A
LEFT JOIN Daily_Inspect B 
ON A.Date_=B.Date_ 
AND A.Rego=B.Rego
```

Comment: thanks very much, I just needed to add a Distinct function to remove the duplicate dates and rego. should be fine.